# Clarification on likelihood maximisation

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, log-linear

From Eisenstein Natural Language Processing textbook, a discriminative log-linear model is defined as $$p(y|x,\theta) = \frac{\exp(\theta^Tf(x,y))}{\sum_{y'} \exp(\theta^Tf(x,y'))}$$

To estimate the optimal parameter of this model, we can perform MLE on a dataset $\{x_i,y_i\}$. In other words finding the parameters that maximise the log-likelihood of observing our data. We are then looking at maximising this quantity w.r.t. $\theta$.
$$\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \sum_i \log p(y_i| x_i, \theta)$$

All this is crystal clear. Now my confusion regards the function we're maximising itself. Because in context of the learning process $y_i$ are supposed to be known labels, what would happen if we were trying to maximising $p(y_i,x_i|\theta)$ rather than $p(y_i|x_i,\theta)$? Do we even know $p(y_i,x_i|\theta)$? How is this related to generative v.s. discriminative modelling?